# What is the meaning of p3p1, p2p1, p1p1 network device?

Tags: networking, ethernet

The devices that used typically to be called eth0 now seem to be p3p1, p2p1, p1p1.

I presume the name means something, but have been unable to find out what.

I think it is not related in any way to W3C's P3P1.

Comment: It's a result of predictable network interface names: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/

Comment: http://it-stuff-i-needed.blogspot.fr/2014/07/getting-rid-of-p3p0-p3p1-p3p-ethernet.html might also help your understanding.

Comment: Hm, OK, that seems kind of reasonable. Except that my p3p1 is definitely an on-motherboard Ethernet adaptor, which lspci gives as 05:00.0, which appears to differ from the explanation is the answer below.  It would *really* help if the developers who make changes like that gave a hint nearby to find what and why.  Ho Hum.  Thanks all.

Comment: My brain has just cried "tilt" with that.  The solution to the problem of inconsistent names is to change the names to something completely different.  I'd have thought a map of conventional names to their actual physical devices would have been more appropriate.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

This is a network interfaces, and it is derived from:

```
Lan-On-Motherboard interfaces: em<port number> (ethernet-on-motherboard <1,2 ..>)

PCI add-in interfaces: p<slot number>p<port number>_<virtual function instance>
```

Comment: Presumably there's a means to ascertain the numbers as above.  The freedesktop page referenced above says "just by looking at lspci you can figure out what the interface is going to be called".  Well, when they say "you", they seem not to be referring to me :-(

Comment: Oh good grief.After an upgrade to 10.04.2 the Ethernet interface p3p1 has vanished, no others have appeared, no ethX has appeared lspci still shows the network device present.

Comment: Ohhh.   Upgrade to 16.04.02 not 10.04.2.  There are also no enXXX devices appeared.  Another issue I forgot.  For some reason this PC seems  not to run with any kernel more recent than 3.13.0-51, so that is the kernel I'm presently obliged to use.  I did the upgrade because I hoped that might have been resolved.

Comment: ifconfig -a    shows an eth0 with a HWaddr. Maybe I have to unwind the changes to get to p3p1 and revert to eth0?  Maddening!